# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS prints left half of page twice

Tags: printing, brother

My Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does not print pages correctly in my Brother HL-2170W printer. My old Ubuntu 16.04 LTS prints well.

The problem in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is that it prints the left half of each page correctly, but prints the left half again on the right side of the page. So I'm trying to print a page that looks like:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| This is my document with text and/or  |
| graphics that should print across     |
| the entire sheet.                     |
|                                       |
|                Total                  |
|                -----                  |
|                12345                  |
+---------------------------------------+
```

But I'm getting:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| This is my documen This is my documen |
| graphics that shou graphics that shou |
| the entire sheet.  the entire sheet.  |
|                                       |
|                Tot                Tot |
|                ---                --- |
|                123                123 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

How can I fix this? It would be funny if I didn't really need it to print for real :/

Comment: Ubuntu versions are done via the Year.Month.  There is no version 2020 or 2016.  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1309294/edit) your question and correct the version numbers you are using.  The only supported versions are Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS and 20.10.

Comment: @Terrance Done. The issue happens in Ubuntu 2020.04 LTS. Works well in Ubuntu 2016.04 LTS.

Comment: In your printer settings *Settings -> Printers* in the Job Options is Pages Per Side set to 1?

Comment: @Terrance Yes. Pages Per Side: 1, Orientation: Portrait, Page Size: US Letter, Paper Source: Automatic, Paper Tray: Plain Paper. Also, I used the "Test Page" button there and it prints the two left halves of the test page as well. Sigh.

Comment: My HL-2170W drivers suggests that it supports 5 resolutions, and I wanted to use the highest resolution (1200 x 600), but I see now that I have it set it to 600 x 600.  Try it?

Comment: @2785528 I switched to 600x600. Now, the Test Page prints well. However, the normal printing is still wrong. This started to happen when I updated the OS. I spent like 2 years without updates and was working well. Sigh. Thank you anyway.